# Unexpected behavior in zip method

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I have the following code:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Test_Changed()
{
    var All = repository.GetProducts().Select(c => c.Price).ToList();
    var Original = All.ToList();
    //The following line updates all prices but should has no effect
    //Because I've used ToList already in All query
    reducer.ReducePrice(amount);
    All.Zip(Original, (f, s) =>
    {
        if (f == s)
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
        return f;
    });
}
```

I'd expected that my test would failed but it is passed successfully. I'm really wondering how is this possible? As clearly shown below the `All` and `Original` variables have same values so why `Assert.Fail();` never executed?

[image]

If I remove the `ToList` from `All` query the test should passed as expected because of deferred execution but when I use `ToList` the later changes should has no effect. So why my test is passes?

Please also see this:

```
var res = All.Zip(Original, (f, s) =>
{
    if (f == s)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    return f;
});
```

The result:

[image]

But the test result:

[image]

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Could your normalize your terminology when stating your results: If the test is supposed to Assert.Fail, but it fails to Fail, then it didn't "passed successfully" -- it "ran to completion" .   It's also OK to use "Asserts" as a verb to mean "called Assert.Fail()" when that is the "Success" condition.

Answer (score 7):

Like many LINQ operations, `Zip` is lazy - your lambda expression is never being executed, because you're calling `Zip` but never using the results.

If you changed your test to do something like:

```
var list = All.Zip(...).ToList();
```

Then I suspect you'll see the assertion fail. (Or call `Count()`, or anything else that iterates over the whole sequence.)

Or as Jamiec says, add an assertion. It could be as simple as:

```
Assert.IsFalse(All.Zip(Original, (f, s) => f == s).Any(x => x));
```

(It really depends on what you're trying to check - different assertions will give you different kinds of information.)

Comment: I tried this already. I see the assertion fail but my test still passes!

Comment: That sounds unlikely to me - please provide a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce the problem. If `Assert.Fail` is executing, that should be throwing an appropriate exception. Note that if you only say the assertion fail in the debugger *when expanding the results in the debugger* that's not the same thing as forcing execution within your actual test.

Comment: @SteveCode The diagnosis of the solution is quite right, but I'd mention that rather than having the LINQ query perform side effects, and doing something like this to ensure those side effects actually happen, it'd be better to have a query that *doesn't* have side effects, and instead searches for the value(s) that you care about, and then have the side effects take place when processing the results of the query.  In this case it would mean writing a query that searches for matching pairs, and then if it finds one *in the result* of the query, it fails.

Comment: @SteveCode you've done exactly what Jon said in the comment above. You've expanded it in the debugger which has enumerated it. You need to force execution in the actual test using `ToList`/`ToArray`

Comment: @JonSkeet So I should use `ToList` at the end of the `Zip` method? Also assigning it to the `var list` is unnecessary right?

Comment: @SteveCode That would make the code work, but it's not good design, and is very fragile, for reasons I mentioned in my previous comment.  The preferable solution is to restructure the query to simply return a value that you can assert on, rather than asserting *in the query itself*.

Answer (score 0):

Your test would be better if you found matching pairs and fail the test if any are found

```
var result = All.Zip(Original, (f, s) =>
    {            
        return f == s;
    });
Assert.IsFalse(result.Where(x => x).Any());
// or: Assert.IsFalse(result.Any(x => x));
```

Comment: This isn't quite right.  `result` is a sequence of booleans.  You need to check if any *are true*, rather than if there are any booleans in the sequence.  Note that `Any` accepts a predicate, so there's no need for a `Where`.

Comment: @Servy I think you saw before update. Sure with the predicate, makes no difference

Comment: Also see the second half of my comment.

Comment: @Servy ditto :D